# how to wrap input box results

Tags: html, css, angularjs, typeahead.js

So, I have an input search box, which returns a dropdown of elements from a db which are strings of various length. I would like to being able to wrap each element which goes over a specific predetermined length let's say (50 chars), and in that case wraps with a smaller font as well. Any idea how to do this?tnks.

```
<input type="text" class ="searchInput" ng-model="searchInput"
            data-provide  = "typeahead"
            typeahead-on-select = "typeAheadOnSelect($item, $model, $label)"
            typeahead-focus-first = "false"
            typeahead-wait-ms = "100ms">
```

for some reason 'textarea' does not work and transforms my entire webpage into a single input box

Comment: In your controller, you can loop through the results from the db on search and then check the length of the string against the predetermined length (50) and set the styles accordingly uisng ng-style or ng-class.

Comment: thnks if you make an answer out of this i will vote it as the answer- although you provided no code - but i did it and will post my answer bit later